# How to make SVG train scheme clickable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have this SVG scheme [image].

The main problem, there is a 'g id='Numbers'' inside the SVG and I can't change the z-index of the numbers, they interfere with clicking on the svg.

I tried to solve this problem by using refs

```
import s from './styles.module.scss'

const ModifySVG = () => 
{
    if (ref.current !== null)
    {
          let seatsList = ref.current.querySelector('#Numbers').childNodes
          seatsList.forEach( (pathTag: any) => 
          {
             pathTag.setAttribute('class', s.numbers);
          })
    }
}
```

Css - style:

```
.numbers{
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: SVG elements do not regard the `z-index`. If you want elements to not be clickable check out [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Comment: i can't click places, because of numbers, and i need to show numbers, but make z-index less than paths of places

Comment: You can position the numbers before the seats elements, apply a transparent color to these to show the numbers. If the seats listen to pointervents, they need to be placed on the last layer. Another solution is to add rects on the last layer, with a transparent fill, and same dimensions and coordinates as the seats, and have them listen to pointer events.

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements do not regard `z-index`. Use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) to click through the `text` elements.

```css
rect:hover{
  fill: orange
}

text:hover{
  fill: orange
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
  <text x="5" y="50" font-size="25px" fill="blue">HOVER</text>
  <text x="5" y="70" font-size="25px" fill="blue">ME!</text>
</svg>

<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
  <text x="5" y="50" font-size="25px" fill="blue" pointer-events="none">HOVER</text>
  <text x="5" y="70" font-size="25px" fill="blue" pointer-events="none">ME?</text>
</svg>
```